# Throw new exceptions for pretend URL address

Tags: java, url, exception

I've made something that retrieves the IP address of a URL I typed in.

```
InetAddress ip = InetAddress.getByName("www.fake.cao");
return ia.getHostAddress();
```

I've also thrown UnknownHostException to try catch the error for incorrect URL's.

The problem is, www.fake.cao is recognised as a genuine URL and returns me a unavailable IP address, and doesn't throw an exception.

Can anyone tell me what can I do to catch these pretentious URL's?

Comment: Awful hack, but - attempt to ping it (or `tracert` it) before returning it?

Comment: the only way to know if it's fake is to test connectivity to it, which then only tells you if it can be connected to from your machine (not if it's "fake")

Comment: If I use www.fake.ascasapaskdjaksd2, surely it should recognise that the last section of the URL would make the entire URL not genuine? But it don't.

Comment: Can you not just establish a connection with a website using `HttpURLConnection` and catch the `UnknownHostException` if its wrong? maybe then throw your own exception from the catch block.

Comment: I tried the same code, and it threw the UnknownHostException.

Comment: Haha, that is so bad of me! When the author said `I've made something that retrieves the IP address` I thought InetAddress was their own creation.

Comment: Mine don't throw unknownHostException, instead it gives me a genuine but error IP address. An IP address that's same for every invalid URL page (redirected unavailable error page from my ISP).

Comment: Oh, you have one of those ISPs that resolve inexistent host names into a page filled with ads. In what way is the IP address "unavailable"?

Comment: 81.200.64.50 is what I get. Virgin Media's error page.

Comment: You could add that one IP address to a list of known synonyms for a broken address

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that your ISP returns a fake page for a non existent DNS domain. That (bad) practice is known as NXDOMAIN redirection.

The JRE cannot tell whether `81.200.64.50` is the actual IP address of `www.fake.cao`, or it is a fake page injected by your ISP.

Other than actually trying to open a socket and check whether it connects (note that it **could** connect even if the host does not exist, for instance, if you try to open an HTTP connection), you might compare the returned IP for that host, with the returned IP of an already known to be invalid host (such as `does-not-exist.invalid`).

```
InetAddress ip = InetAddress.getByName("www.fake.cao");

InetAddress fake;
try {
   fake = InetAddress.getByName("does-not-exist.invalid");      
} catch (UnknownHostException e) {
   //www.fake.cao exists, but invalid does not
   return ip;
} 
if (Arrays.equals(ip.getAddress(),fake.getAddress())) {
    //both ip and fake resolves to the same IP
    throw new UnknownHostException();
}

//invalid does exist, but it is different from ip
return ip;
```

This approach isn't complete, because your ISP might be returning different addresses for different non-existent hosts, but at least tries to address the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Attempt to open a socket to the address, that will throw an exception if the address is invalid.

Answer (score 1):

By the IP specification, address 0.0.0.0 denotes a host that is unavailable, invalid or unknown. If you do not get an exception for incorrect URLs, maybe you can check the IP address. If it is 0.0.0.0, then the host probably doesn't exist.

If you get some generic not-exists address from your ISP, then maybe you can try to perform a manual NS lookup. Basically you would have to rewrite the entire code in the InetAddress class. That would comprise obtaining a DNS server IP address, opening a socket to it, posting a NS query and reading a parsing the response.

If you are not that into platform independence, you can use JNI to hookup to a platform DNS tool. `nslookup.exe` for Windows, for example.

Comment: I don't get 0.0.0.0, but perhaps I can add the IP address I'm getting in a error IP address list? But that's not entirely what I'm after.